# Log / report for emails sent using Events > Find Participants?

Tags: civievent, email

I sent a dozen or so emails using Events > Find Participants > Email - Send now. At least some of them arrived successfully (recipients are responding), but I can't find a log or report in CiviCRM that can confirm that they were all sent. Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

This new [Transaction Mail](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional) extension that Fuzion published won't help your specific problem but would help in the future in as much as it would report back on Bounces for those.